# WPF Grid: MouseUp event is not fired after mouse move

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mouseevent

have discovered that the Mouse up work properly most of the time, they just do not get fired when my mouse  has begun moving after the initial click. I have a pretty heavy mouse move event. So the only conclusion i can draw is that the mouse move event is some how preventing the mouse button up event from firing. Any thoughts please.

Note: I am using MVVM model.

```
<Grid >
    <Image x:Name="DynamicJoystickWindow" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>

            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseUp" >
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding JoystickMouseUp_Dynamic}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
            </i:EventTrigger>

            <!--<i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseUp" >
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding JoystickMouseUp_Dynamic}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
            </i:EventTrigger>-->

            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding JoystickMouseDown_Dynamic}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
            </i:EventTrigger>

            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseMove" >
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding JoystickMouseMove_Dynamic}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
            </i:EventTrigger>

            <!--<i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove" >
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding JoystickMouseMove_Dynamic}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
            </i:EventTrigger>-->

        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding RenderScaleTransform}" ScaleY="{Binding RenderScaleTransform}"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources/transparent.png"/>
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.3" />
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

Comment: If you moved the mouse outside the boundary of the image - it shouldn't raise.

Comment: @Hamlet Hakobyan - FYI. I am doing all the mouse operations with in the grid.

Comment: Could you tell me why VS complains about cmd:EventToCommand in my  code? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I do not observe the behavior you describe, so I would suggest you to simplify your problem to understand what's going on.

For example, remove your image and work only with the grid to see if something change.

I used the following code and it works well for me:

```
 <Grid x:Name="DynamicJoystickWindow" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Background="Blue">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>

                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseUp" >
                        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding JoystickMouseUp_Dynamic}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>

                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
                        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding JoystickMouseDown_Dynamic}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>

                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseMove" >
                        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding JoystickMouseMove_Dynamic}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>

                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Grid>
```

The only case where event is not fired is when I finish my move outside of the grid.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you know why My XAML is complaining about the command:EventToCommand ? what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. Problem is, I had the image size smaller than the grid. as @Ouarzy suggested, had grid only and tried. the mouse events works as expected.